# In android., how to add jingle during video file getting downloaded from server

Tags: java, android, xmpp, jingle

In this code i need to apply jingle when the video is getting downloaded from the server to mobile device

```
code : This the main activity which is java file where the videos are downloaded from server and getting situated in android device and will be played in video view
```

MainActivity.java
    package ivmshd.mcu.com.demo;

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.io.File;

import static android.R.attr.path;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private long enqueue;
private DownloadManager dm;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {


                            VideoView view= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    enter code here

                            String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                            view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                DownloadManager.Request request =new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://eZeeReview.com/login/pages/examples/video/1.mp4"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
        final VideoView videoView;

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("http://eZeeReview.com/login/pages/examples/video/1.mp4");
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

    }
    public void showDownload(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);

        startActivity(i);
    }

}


XML File: In this code the widgets are applied

widgets are like Video view and 2 buttons
```

where videos are played in video view.This videos are the videos which are fetched from server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:text="Start Download" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"></Button>

    <Button android:text="View Downloads" android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showDownload"></Button>

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the `jingle`? Is it some audio?

Comment: Jingle is like which are used during file transfer i.e if the videos are getting downloaded from  server,during that time jingle will be played in form of videos

Comment: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html

Comment: you can check the above link to know abt that

Comment: ok now I see that it isn't something I have a clue in.